# How can I display Video and Images in TextView or any other View that can contain texts and media except webview

Tags: java, android

I need to display an article with Texts, Images and Videos without using a WebView. Is it possible? I just don't want the view to load!

Comment: You can display an image inside a TextView using an `ImageSpan`, but I'm not aware of any way to show a video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Text view" as the name suggests is for texts. Use an 'Image view' instead to hold images or a 'Video view'to hold videos in your activities. All the best

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom view which you can parameterise to show
1. text (with just textView)
2. text+images (textview with image view in a layout)
3.text+videos (textview+ VideoView)

Now use this class as a view in your layout and in your activity, pass it the corresponding parameters and make it look the way you want.